# iterate over an object and transform into an array type

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML class that reads an XML file and allows for it to be accessed like this

```
<config>
    <directory>
        <mvc>
             <model>model</model>
        </mvc>
    </directory>
</config>

echo $xml->config->directory->mvc->model
```

(assuming the object has been passed to a variable `$xml`)

outputs

```
model
```

I want to turn each parent/child/value nodes into an array. So

```
echo $xmlArr['config']['directory']['mvc']['model']

echo's model
```

I was in the process of using a `foreach` loop set up, but then realized that if the XML file has deep level of nested nodes, then my foreach statements would only cover so many levels. The XML files are a dynamic variable that I cannot account for and would need a dynamic method to be able to recursively iterate through the nodes and append them as array index.

Comment: It is definitely possible to convert XML to an array, either using some of the XML libraries build into PHP or with just recursive looping. There are two catches though that don't quite match up.  1) Attributes.  Do you just make a branch off of the element, like other libraries do? 2) inline elements.  Not so much in most XML, but in HTML, how do you indicate "this array value has a sub-array mid-way through"?

Comment: Or look here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3598-PHP-Parse-a-XML-document-into-a-nested-array.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP you can use `xml_parse_into_struct` method to convert XML structure to arrays

**Reference:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Comment: looks like i was somewhat on the right path, but i need alot more work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/book.xml.php).

For each depth level you can create an array in your loop and after iterating append it to your main array.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php